# How to link merge commits

Tags: git, pycharm, git-merge

If I merge two branches in PyCharm with commit using `Merge into current`, the commit is correctly linked to its parent. In the Git tab, this shows as a special commit, which I'll refer to as a "merge commit". The automatic comment is in a darker font and it follows the template `Merge branch <branch name>`. The merge commit details identify the hash of the parent commit and the PyCharm Git log diagram shows the merge visually by linking from the parent to the child with a line. There is clearly some special metadata in a merge commit beyond a regular commit at the git level that PyCharm populates and reads from when rendering the diagram.

My problem is that this does not occur when I merge with `--no-commit` using the Git/Merge menu option. Instead of committing, PyCharm loads the merge changes in the staging area for me to review, which is what I want. But when I then commit the changes to the target branch, *this commit does not appear as a merge commit*. It's missing the parent linkage metadata, so it's not formally displayed with a linked line as a merge in the PyCharm git log, but rather as a normal, unlinked commit on the target branch. The merge is thus unofficial, because the code is merged, but the git tree does not show it.

Am I doing it wrong? How can I make this manual, `--no-commit` merge an official merge commit in git?

Answer (score 1):

This is pycharm doing this to you. In Git, when you merge --no-commit and subsequently make the commit, the second parent is recorded.